# Display phone numbers from the Contacts app in a List View

Tags: swift, swiftui

The following code successfully fetches and displays the name and last name of all of the contacts in the Contacts app, what I'm struggling with is displaying the phone numbers.

How can the phone numbers be displayed in a lits view?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var contacts:[CNContact] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Conctacts")
                .font(.title)
            List {
                ForEach(contacts, id:\.self) { contact in
                    VStack{
                        HStack{
                            Text("\(contact.givenName)")
                            Text("\(contact.familyName)")
                                .fontWeight(.bold)
                            Spacer()
                            Button {
                                print("Edit button was tapped")
                            } label: {
                                Image(systemName:"person.crop.circle.fill.badge.plus")
                                    .font(.title3)
                                    .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                            }
                            .buttonStyle(.plain)
                        }
                        Text("\(contact.phoneNumbers[0])")
                    }
                }
            }
            .onAppear{
                Task.init{
                    await fetchAllContacts()
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
    
    func fetchAllContacts() async{
        let store = CNContactStore()
        let keys = [CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey, CNContactFamilyNameKey] as [CNKeyDescriptor]
        let fetchRequest = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: keys)
        
        do{
            try store.enumerateContacts(with: fetchRequest, usingBlock: { contact, result in
                
                contacts.append(contact)
            })
        }
        catch{
           print ("Error")
        }
    }
}
```

In the following picture, I show what I'm currently getting on the left and what I'm expecting on the right.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update `Text("\(contact.phoneNumbers[0])")` to:

```
Text(contact.phoneNumbers[0].value.stringValue)
```

- `phoneNumbers` is `[CNLabeledValue<CNPhoneNumber>]`
- `phoneNumbers[0]` is `CNLabeledValue<CNPhoneNumber>`
- `phoneNumbers[0].value` is `CNPhoneNumber`
- `phoneNumbers[0].value.stringValue` is `String` representing the phone number.

---

You might want to use `phoneNumbers.first` and deal with the optional since not all contacts have a phone number.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot for the good information and advice.